# Intuition for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) f'(x) \,dx=0$ where $f(x) \to 0$ when $x \to \pm \infty$

Tags: calculus

Assume $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm\infty}f(x) = 0,\:\:\: f(x)\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$$

For this case, I saw a theorem that says that: $$\int_{-\infty}^{{\infty}}f(x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\:dx = 0$$ (not hard to prove with integration by parts)

Is there any intuition for this result? I can see the intuition only in the case where f(x) is symmetric. We have: $$df \approx \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\:dx,$$ so the integrand is the product of f(x) and the infinitesimal addition to f at x's neighborhood, df(x). Thanks to the symmetry we have: $$df(-x)f(-x)=df(-x)f(x)=-df(x)f(x)$$ so the values of the integrand at x,-x cancel out and we have a total sum of 0.
Thanks!

Comment: What functional spaces are we talking here? Sobolev space $H^2$?

Comment: $$C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$$

Comment: You can also use MathJax in your question title, as I've just edited.

Comment: One argument is that the integrand is the rate of change of $f^2$ which has no net change - but that's just summarizing the known proof.

Comment: I know it's not the point, but I think $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is not a strong enough condition to guarantee convergence: consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \sin(x^4)$.

Answer (score -2):

The conditions imply that $f$ is smooth enough to use integration by parts, for which we find that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f'(x)dx = [f^2(x)]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)f(x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f'(x)dx
$$
so the integral is equal to the negative of itself, and hence it is zero. Note here that you really need to replace all the $\pm \infty$ with finite limits and then take the limit at the end.

Comment: Pls look again at the question: OP asks for intuition of this result, and not its proof based on integration by parts. This may explain why your correct statement attracts downvotes as it is not considered as an answer.